# Cant change color of circles

Tags: html, css

There is my website, how to make change color for circles. I can't find css rule for that. 
Check my website http://avto-podberem.ru/

```
     <div data-date="2016-5-01 00:00:00" class="DateCountdown"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: What are you trying to change, the outer circle color?

Comment: Yeah i try do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your circles are being drawn via the [jquery circle progress](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) plugin.

It's being initialized and called in [script.js](http://avto-podberem.ru/js/script.js).

To change the circular color, find the string `rgba(11,119,80, 1)` and change it to another `rgba()` color.